# Terraform: The parameter Origin DomainName does not refer to a valid S3 bucket

Tags: terraform, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to create a Cloudfront distribution with Terraform and getting this error: `error creating CloudFront Distribution: InvalidArgument: The parameter Origin DomainName does not refer to a valid S3 bucket`, but I'm specifiying the public DNS address of an EC2 instance and not S3 bucket address in the config. How this can be fixed?

Terraform file:

```
resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "distribution" {

  origin {
    domain_name = aws_instance.instance.public_dns
    origin_id   = var.name
    custom_origin_config {
      http_port              = "80"
      https_port             = "443"
      origin_protocol_policy = "http-only"
      origin_ssl_protocols   = ["TLSv1", "TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2"]
    }
  }

  enabled             = false
  is_ipv6_enabled     = true

  default_cache_behavior {
    allowed_methods  = ["DELETE", "GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS", "PATCH", "POST", "PUT"]
    cached_methods   = ["GET", "HEAD"]
    target_origin_id = var.name

    forwarded_values {
      query_string = true

      cookies {
        forward = "all"
      }
    }

    viewer_protocol_policy = "redirect-to-https"
    min_ttl                = 0
    default_ttl            = 86400
    max_ttl                = 31536000
  }
 
  price_class = "PriceClass_All"

  restrictions {
    geo_restriction {
      restriction_type = "none"
    }
  }

  viewer_certificate {
    acm_certificate_arn = aws_acm_certificate.cert.id
    ssl_support_method = "sni-only"
  }

  depends_on = [
    aws_acm_certificate.cert,
  ]
}
```

Comment: What is `var.name`?

Comment: @Marcin It's a domain name, just a string to use as a unique Origin Id

Comment: It's strange, but when I changed enabled to true Terraform successfully created a distribution

Comment: As long it works, then its good:-)

Comment: you need to keep *enabled=true*  then only it will work

Answer (score 3):

I also face same issue, i had one file (with name s3.tf) containing below code

```
data "aws_s3_bucket" "imagesBucket" {
    bucket = "${var.ImagesS3Bucket}"
}
```

while creating cloud-distribution(in another file with name as cloudfront.tf), i just pointed to the bucket_domain_name of the s3 bucket and it works fine.

```
resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "distribution" {
    origin {
        origin_id   = "cd_s3_bucket"
        domain_name = "${data.aws_s3_bucket.imagesBucket.bucket_domain_name}"
    }

    enabled = true

    default_cache_behavior {
        allowed_methods  = ["DELETE", "GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS", "PATCH", "POST", "PUT"]
        cached_methods   = ["GET", "HEAD"]
        target_origin_id = "cd_s3_bucket"

        default_ttl = 0
        min_ttl     = 0
        max_ttl     = 0

       forwarded_values {
           query_string = true
           cookies {
               forward = "all"
           }
       }

       viewer_protocol_policy = "https-only"
    }

    price_class     = "PriceClass_100"
    is_ipv6_enabled = true
    restrictions {
        geo_restriction {
            restriction_type = "none"
        }
    }

    viewer_certificate {
        cloudfront_default_certificate = true
    }
}
```

Although, we can put all code in single terraform file, but for better code readability, we segregate the code to different files.